# PYTHON py2exe makes too many files.. how do I execute only one .EXE file?

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

After I make an exe file, there are many files such as .pyd that my exe depend on them..
I want to make a program with only one exe file which will be handie..
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use [pyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki) with the `-F` options.

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe is a tool provides an exe application which can be run without installing python interpreter, after packaging you find your exe and dlls of interpreter and all modules... In dist folder. It does nt provide all in one exe, use pyinstaller instead

Comment: Thank you very much! I used it. works perfectly good.